# karma chrome not loading.its giving up after two attempts

Tags: angularjs, google-chrome, ionic-framework, jasmine, karma-jasmine

I'm integrating Jasmine and karma for unit testing my ionic app.
I'm following this [blog](http://gonehybrid.com/how-to-write-automated-tests-for-your-ionic-app-part-2/).

When i run the karma start command i keep getting this result.

23 02 2017 16:39:18.508:WARN [karma]: No captured browser, open 
23 02 2017 16:39:18.517:INFO [karma]: Karma v1.5.0 server started at http://0.0.0.0:9876/
23 02 2017 16:39:18.517:INFO [launcher]: Launching browser Chrome with unlimited concurrency
23 02 2017 16:39:18.536:INFO [launcher]: Starting browser Chrome
23 02 2017 16:40:18.537:WARN [launcher]: Chrome have not captured in 60000 ms, killing.
23 02 2017 16:40:18.910:INFO [launcher]: Trying to start Chrome again (1/2).
23 02 2017 16:41:18.911:WARN [launcher]: Chrome have not captured in 60000 ms, killing.
23 02 2017 16:41:19.357:INFO [launcher]: Trying to start Chrome again (2/2).

Tried with PhantomJS also

Same error

Launching browser PhantomJS with unlimited concurrency
23 02 2017 17:44:30.214:INFO [launcher]: Starting browser PhantomJS

23 02 2017 17:45:30.215:WARN [launcher]: PhantomJS have not captured in 60000 ms, killing.

23 02 2017 17:45:30.238:INFO [launcher]: Trying to start PhantomJS again (1/2).
23 02 2017 17:46:30.239:WARN [launcher]: PhantomJS have not captured in 60000 ms, killing.

23 02 2017 17:46:30.246:INFO [launcher]: Trying to start PhantomJS again (2/2).

23 02 2017 17:47:30.247:WARN [launcher]: PhantomJS have not captured in 60000 ms, killing.

23 02 2017 17:47:30.254:ERROR [launcher]: PhantomJS failed 2 times (timeout). Giving up.

Config

```html
// Karma configuration
// Generated on Thu Feb 23 2017 10:39:27 GMT+0530 (IST)

module.exports = function(config) {
  config.set({

    // base path that will be used to resolve all patterns (eg. files, exclude)
    basePath: '',


    // frameworks to use
    // available frameworks: https://npmjs.org/browse/keyword/karma-adapter
    frameworks: ['jasmine'],


    // list of files / patterns to load in the browser
    files: [
      '../www/lib/ionic/js/ionic.bundle.js',
      '../www/js/**/*.js',
      '../tests/unit-tests/**/*.js',
      '../node_modules/angular-mocks/angular-mocks.js'
    ],



    // list of files to exclude
    exclude: [
    ],


    // preprocess matching files before serving them to the browser
    // available preprocessors: https://npmjs.org/browse/keyword/karma-preprocessor
    preprocessors: {
    },


    // test results reporter to use
    // possible values: 'dots', 'progress'
    // available reporters: https://npmjs.org/browse/keyword/karma-reporter
    reporters: ['progress'],


    // web server port
    port: 9876,


    // enable / disable colors in the output (reporters and logs)
    colors: true,


    // level of logging
    // possible values: config.LOG_DISABLE || config.LOG_ERROR || config.LOG_WARN || config.LOG_INFO || config.LOG_DEBUG
    logLevel: config.LOG_INFO,


    // enable / disable watching file and executing tests whenever any file changes
    autoWatch: true,


    // start these browsers
    // available browser launchers: https://npmjs.org/browse/keyword/karma-launcher
   // browsers: ['PhantomJS'],
   browsers: ['Chrome'],
    // customLaunchers: {
    //   Chrome_no_sandbox: {
    //     base: 'Chrome',
    //     flags: ['--no-sandbox']
    //   }
    // },
     plugins:[
             'karma-jasmine',
             'karma-phantomjs-launcher',
             'karma-chrome-launcher'
             ],
    




    // Continuous Integration mode
    // if true, Karma captures browsers, runs the tests and exits
    singleRun: false,


    // Concurrency level
    // how many browser should be started simultaneous
    concurrency: Infinity,
    
  })
}
```

Please help

Thanks!

Comment: Please check if the same port is used by some other application.

Comment: Checked its not being used by any other process.
The url that open looks like this
http://localhost:9876/?id=74605681

Comment: Please upload your karma.conf.js

Comment: Updated the question with conf file

Comment: did you solve the issue?

Answer (score 1):

This is the top Google result for this question, so even though it's old I hope my answer helps someone.

In our case the issue was caused by multiple files importing from the wrong library.  This seems strange since you would think that Karma would throw an error rather than just refusing to open Chrome, but altering our import statements got us past the issue.

```
import { ChangeDetectionStrategy } from "@angular/core";
```

NOT AS OUR FILES HAD IT: import { ChangeDetectionStrategy } from "@angular/compiler/src/core";

Comment: This was also the case for me. I had 2 unused imports to things in `@angular/compiler`; removing those made everything work again. This was only broken in my CI server and ran fine locally, which had me stumped for a while.

Answer (score 0):

[This](https://community.codeship.com/t/chrome-have-not-captured-in-60000-ms-killing/1177/2) says you should try add the below code to karma.conf.js file:

```
browsers: ['Chrome_no_sandbox'],
    customLaunchers: {
      Chrome_no_sandbox: {
        base: 'Chrome',
        flags: ['--no-sandbox']
      }
    }
```

Comment: Same result with this also.

Comment: Which version of chrome are you using.

Comment: chrome:Version 56.0.2924.87 (64-bit)
Ubuntu 16.04LTS

Comment: Did you try using Phantom browser for karma

Comment: tried that also,but that is also not working
 Cannot load browser "PhantomJs": it is not registered! Perhaps you are missing some plugin?
23 02 2017 17:37:31.509:ERROR [karma]: Found 1 load error.
Tried correcting it also with help  from this link:
https://julienprog.wordpress.com/2016/10/12/automate-unit-testing-of-javascripts-with-karma-runner/

Answer (score 0):

Try increasing browserDisconnectTolerance. Reasons could be different, from the wrong path in karma.config to some flaky npm run.